# Should I use PHP or Javascript for page refreshing?

Tags: javascript, php, refresh

I would like to ask for your opinion on the topic. I can make my page refresh with both of these methods, but I do not know if they have any drawbacks. So, which one should I use?

Edit:

I'm talking about header('Refresh:0') in PHP and location.reload() in javascript.(Sorry, I forgot them first)

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh". Under what conditions do you want to do this? What JS code would you use? What PHP code would you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The draw back with doing this via JavaScript is that you are limiting this feature to users who do not have JavaScript running in their browser. If it's important that the page refresh for all users then I would suggest not doing it via JavaScript.

Doing it via PHP would run for all users, but the bigger question is why do you need to refresh the page? And could you achieve the same thing without refreshing the page?

Comment: Well, now that you mention it, I could make it work without refreshing. I don't know why didn't I think of that. By the way, it's about logging a user in with browser cookie.

Comment: I would only refresh the page if absolutely necessary, it can often be confusing to the user if something happens but they just see the same page.

Comment: Yup, it works nicely without refresh. Thank you!